# Handling http errors before parsing xml file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have this NSXMLParser that parsing an XML file from a webserver

```
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ep.samico.dk/valuta.xml"]];
```

I want my app to handle http errors, so it displays an error if cant connect to the server..

How can i check the url for response before i parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the data first, then feed it to the parser. `NSData` can do this for you.

Comment: Also there are some nice libaries out there that can really help. Like: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which has a special [AFXMLRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFXMLRequestOperation.h). This calls will help you do fetching of XML async.